# How to make git to sync folder structures in a new commit and push it to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a simple project with a folder structure like this:

```
├── css
│   └── style.ccs
└── index.html
```

I added files to the stage with `git add index.html css/style.css` and then committed. Then I pushed it to a newly created GitHub repository.

After that, I have decided to change the structure of my project to:

```
├── index.html
└── resources
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── image
    │   ├── camp.jpeg
    │   └── phone.png
    └── video
        └── excursion.mp4
```

I added files to stage with `git add index.html resources/*`, committed and pushed to the same repository on GitHub.

After checking GitHub, I noticed that the `css/style.css` was still present there.

Can I alter that behaviour that way, so if the folder is not present on the new commit it will be deleted from GitHub repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't track if a file's state changed, it just tracks the state of the folder and commits what you include with `git add`. A "move" is equivalent to a file being deleted and a new file of the same content being created elsewhere.

Since you didn't include the deleted file in your `git add` command, git didn't include the file being "deleted" in your commit.

If you ran `git add index.html resources/* css/*` instead, the file would have been removed (moved) as you intended.

You can also use the `git mv` command to avoid mistakes of this nature.